# Django object versions

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to store objects in my database with a version. So whenever there is a change to the object, a new object is created with a higher version. This allows objects from other models still using the older version of the object.

I don't want versioning for my modesl, but for my objects.

Example:
Let's say for a webshop one model is the item the other is the order. If some customer places an order he of course wants to buy exactly the item that he saw when placing the order. But if the item changes price this should not have any influence on the already placed orders but only on the future orders.

Comment: You need to give some code snippet to explain your point better.

Comment: @AnkurGupta this is more a general question. Not specific to my models.

Comment: The example you later put is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would be a practical solution to a webshop example as you only need certain data to remain frozen and it's generally more practical to just copy the name, SKU and price to the ordered item model. You most likely don't need to freeze stuff like stock levels, detailed descriptions or images.

However since you're asking in general, you might want to take a look at:

http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/versioning/

Comment: That is what Google suggested, but isn't this only for versioning models?

Comment: What do you mean when you say “versioning models”? To me “versioning models” would be what South does—provide database migrations between various versions of the schema.

Comment: Versioning models is needed if you change your models after your database is already populated with data. In my case I don't want to change my models at all. All I want to do is change objects. Like editing a single row in the database. But I don't want to lose the overwritten data. The problem is that with foreign keys I want to prevent linking to the wrong version of the object.

Comment: All of these are for data versioning, not schema versioning. So you get multiple rows for different versions of the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to create new object each time you call `save`, just clear it's pk.

```
class PersistentModel(models.Model) 
   def save(self):
        if self.pk is not None:
            self.pk = None
        return super(PersistentModel, self).save()
```